# How to show this Holder bound?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Define the seminorm on the space $S=[0,1]\times[0,T]$
$$\mid u\mid_{\alpha} = \sup\frac{|u(x, t) - u(y,s)|}{(|x-y|^2 + |t-s|)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}}}.$$
Define the norms on the same space
$$\lVert u \rVert_{C^{0, \alpha}} = \lVert u \rVert_{C^0} + \mid u\mid_{\alpha}$$
and
$$\lVert u \rVert_{C^{2, \alpha}} = \lVert u \rVert_{C^0} +\lVert u_x \rVert_{C^0}+\lVert u_{xx} \rVert_{C^0}+\lVert u_t \rVert_{C^0}+ \mid u_{xx}\mid_{\alpha} + \mid u_t\mid_{\alpha}.$$

Suppose that $\lVert u \rVert_{C^2, \alpha} \leq C$ where $C$ is a constant. Let $a, b, c \in C^{0, \alpha}$. How can I show that
$$\lVert au_{xx} + bu_x + cu\rVert_{C^{0, \alpha}} \leq K\lVert u \rVert_{C^{2, \alpha}}$$
for some constant $K$?

Or equivalently, want to show that
$$\sup_{\lVert u \rVert_{C^{2,\alpha}} \leq C_1}\lVert au_{xx} + bu_x + cu\rVert_{C^{0, \alpha}} \leq K_1$$

(ALL the above norms are over the compact set $S$).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f,g\in C^{\alpha}(S)$, then for all $(x,t),(x',t')\in S$, we have 
\begin{align}
|f\cdot g(x,t)-f\cdot g(x',t')|&=|f(x,t)(g(x,t)-g(x',t'))+g(x',t')f(x,t)-f(x',t')g(x',t')|\\\
&\leq \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}|g(x,t)-g(x',t')|+\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}|f(x,t)-f(x',t')|,
\end{align}
hence 
\begin{equation}\[f\cdot g\]_{\alpha}\leq \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\[g\]_{\alpha}+\lVert g\rVert_{\infty} \[f\]_{\alpha}.
\end{equation}
We deduce that 
\begin{align}
\lVert au_{xx}+bu_x+cu\rVert_{C^{0,\alpha}}&\leq \max(\lVert a\rVert_{\infty},\lVert b\rVert_{\infty},\lVert c\rVert_{\infty})(\lVert u_{xx}\rVert_{\infty}+\lVert u_x\rVert_{\infty}+\lVert u\rVert_{\infty})\\\
&+\max(\lVert a\rVert_{\infty},\lVert b\rVert_{\infty},\lVert c\rVert_{\infty})(\[ u_{xx}\]_{\alpha}+\[u_x\]_{\alpha}+\[u\]_{\alpha}) \\\
&+\max(\[a\]_{\alpha},\[b\]_{\alpha},\[c\]_{\alpha})(\lVert u_{xx}\rVert_{\infty}+\lVert u_x\rVert_{\infty}+\lVert u\rVert_{\infty})\\\
&\leq \max(\max(\[a\]_{\alpha},\[b\]_{\alpha},\[c\]_{\alpha}),\max(\lVert a\rVert_{\infty},\lVert b\rVert_{\infty},\lVert c\rVert_{\infty}))\lVert u\rVert_{C^{2,\alpha}}.
\end{align}
We can get an equivalent norm on $C^{2,\alpha}(S)$ defining 
\begin{equation}\lVert u\rVert:=\[u\]_{\alpha}+\lVert u\rVert_{\infty}+\[u_t\]_{\alpha}+\lVert u_t\rVert_{\infty}+\[u_x\]_{\alpha}+\lVert u_x\rVert_{\infty}+\[u_{xx}\]_{\alpha}+\lVert u_{xx}\rVert_{\infty}.
\end{equation}
This can be shown using mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see how you get the last inequality. The $C^{2,\alpha}$ norm of $u$ does not include the seminorms $[u_x]_{\alpha}$ and $[u]_{\alpha}$ that are present on the lhs unfortunately.

Comment: I hope it's not a problem, because with mean value theorem we get an equivalent norm when we include them. 

Comment: Thanks. I believe you're right but I can't show how $[u]_\alpha$ and $[u_x]_{\alpha}$ are bounded above by something useful using the MVT. For $[u]_{\alpha}$, I get something like needing to show $\sup\left(\frac{(x-y)^2 + (t-s)^2}{(|x-y|^2 + |t-s|)^{\alpha}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} < \infty.$

Does that look about what you meant?

Comment: In your last expression (as in the first of the OP), a square is missing, I think ($|t-s|^{\color{red}2}$). This supremum can be bounded by a constant involving the diameter of the compact, namely, $\operatorname{diam}(S)^{1-\alpha}$.

Comment: I don't think that square should be there. From the source I'm using and from Krylov's book, the powers of |x-y| and |t-s| are different. I'm not really sure what the point of defining the space in such a way is though. 

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, but do you know how I can bound $[u_x]_\alpha$? I don't think I can get anything from using the MVT or the mean value inequality (I get a $u_{xt}$ term which I can't do anything with).

Comment: Hmm. Might be able to do something by adding and subtracting the same term in the numerator.

Comment: @Davide do you think I just create a new norm by adding on $[u_x]_\alpha$? It shouldn't break anything...